# how to configure maven to use local artifact

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

I'm trying to modify an existing project **X** and to test it there is another project **Y** that use the X project's jar (I know it is not the best way to do tests, but there is some constraints) 
My question is : how to configure maven to use the local version of the project X jar (there is other version of X jar ) ? 
I tried to change the dependency version but i t doesn't work, I also disable update of local repo and run mvn command offline, but none of these are working .

Answer (score 1):

Build project X locally with a different version (like `1.2.3-TEST-SNAPSHOT`) and reference this version in project Y.

If the projects are both Eclipse projects, you can also use Eclipse workspace resolution to directly resolve against the other project (inside Eclipse).

Comment: this is what I did, but  apparently the project X have in its dependency hierarchy references to other version of project Y, therefore when I build project X, I found two jars of project Y whith different version, and when debugging it is the other version that is used (not the one that I want ),
for eclipse I cannot use it (it another story..)

Comment: If project X has project Y as dependency, you _cannot_ use X as dependency for Y because this would be a cyclic dependency. You cannot have dependency hierarchies like Y->...->X->...->Y.

Comment: I made a mistake, its project Y which apparently have dependency to to project Z which use another version of project X (I think because I don't know the source of the other version of project X, I tried **mvn clean install -Dverbose -include=X, but it doesn't return anything...)

Comment: If you declare the dependency on X in your project Y (in the `<dependencies>`) you will get exactly the specified version. You can check with with `mvn dependency:list`.

Comment: that's what I think, but the project's Y WEB-INF/lib folder contains two version projects X, I checked and rechecked the poms of Y and always it is the version of X that I want was used, but when build the project I find two versions

Comment: Two possible reasons: 1. You did not use `mvn clean install`. 2. Project X exists with different groupIds.

Comment: That is the problem :
1. i'm using clean install, 
2.I verify  the grpID and artifactID if the two versions jar's and they are the same

Comment: Then you might have activated some strange additional plugin that copies dependencies through the back door.

Answer (score 0):

Ok,
The first, You must build project X, choose maven build or run mvn clean install.
Then after success, you can check in folder m2/repository///bla bla. You can see file X.jar
In file pom of project Y, you add dependency of project X.
GroupID and ArtifactID of project X you can see in file pom of project X.

Comment: I think that after clean install command, the jar will be in target folder not in m2 repo

Answer (score -1):

1. Build your project X and then
2. Build project Y in offline mode using option o, something like this:
   mvn -o clean install
   -O option will not download X's version from the remote repository. It will use $M2_HOME version of X on your local repository which was installed by your build.